# Why does lithium aluminium hydride reduce a ketone over enolising the ketone?

Tags: organic-chemistry

By lithium aluminium hydride enolising the ketone, hydrogen gas is produced.

This is very entropically favourable, so why does this not happen and rather we get addition of the hydride ion to the carbonyl?

Comment: LAH is better as reductant then base. Precise answer needs mechanism of reduction.

Comment: If the things were solved by thermodynamics alone, then most part of organic chemistry would not _exist_.

Comment: First you get Aluminium binding to the ketone - this is very important